# Rails Application Layout not included

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, layout, partials

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

  def test
    render :partial => 'test'
  end

end
```

The above code doesn't include the default application layout in the _test.erb partial

However If I use

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

  def test
  end

end
```

The partial test.erb is loaded with the default application.html layout

Also If I use

```
render :partial => 'test', :layout => 'application'
```

I get an error because rails searched for _application.html whereas the default layout is application.html

Using the below code fragment where I include layout 'application' in the controller too doesn't load the application.html layout.

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

  layout 'application'

  def test
    render :partial => 'test'
  end

end
```

Am I doing something wrong or does Rails just not include application layout as the default layout when we render a partial.

Comment: Why are you rendering partial from controller?

Comment: I want to pass some locals to my partial

Something like

render :partial => 'test', locals: { user: user }

Comment: I am not sure but did you try like this: `render :partial => 'test', :layout => true`

Comment: I think rendering the partial from controller is wrong. Instead you must create a view and render the partial in the view

Comment: How do I pass my local variables to a partial without using render. I dont think using too many @instance variables is a good practice

Answer (score 0):

It's better to render partials from the view.

```
<%= render "path/to/partial", :variable => @variable %>
```